# Update just one field from backup

Tags: t-sql

I'm looking to restore one field from a backup and can't find the syntax for an update statement that can look at 2 different catalogs.

Seems like it should be something fairly close to:

```
update users set idUserCompany = 
   (select idUserCompany from .myBackup.dbo.users uT) 
where uT.idUser = idUser
```

Note: Backup used here in a generic sense. The point is that i have good data in the database named .myBackup and need to pull one file into my production db where a match exists in the idUser field between backup and production.

How's a join look in an update statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK that's not how `BACKUP` is designed to work, not even close.

What I've had to do is `RESTORE` to a new database, then do an `UPDATE` via a `JOIN` on the relevant key.

Comment: I suppose you've earned that much but to be honest (in the sense of constructive fb) i'm not _entirely happy w/how badly you misread my original intent. seems pretty obvious i wasn't talking about SQL BACKUP. joins are way less obvious. thx again.

Answer (score 0):

Thankx for the pointer to JOIN:

```
update Users set users.idUserCompany = backup.idUserCompany
 from Users inner join .myBackup.dbo.users as old 
on users.idUser = old.idUser
```